# Java convert time zone

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, java-7

In Java 7 what is the best way to both hold a DateTime with an explicit time zone and to convert it to a different timezone.

And when I say convert, the time (and possibly date) is converted for the difference between the timezone on and the one converting to. So converting from PST to EST, it's not just the timezone in the object changes to EST, but 3 hours are added to the time component, possibly causing the date to roll over by 1 day.

What I must handle is toLocalTime() and toUtcTime(). I'd prefer being able to handle converting to any timezone.

Comment: Store a `Date` in UTC. Let is system always deal with dates in UTC if you can. When you recieve date information into the system, covert the UTC and when you print out of the system covert to the specified time zone. This is fairly easy to do with [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)).

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone), http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant(org.threeten.bp.ZoneId)

Comment: FYI: switching to Java 8 would make you life much easier - the new Date Time API is much more sane.

Comment: I concur with JB Nizet, use the Java 8 Time API (JSR-310) [Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). That way your code is prepared for the future, i.e. when you finally leaving the obsolete Java 7 behind.

Comment: Unfortunately we're stuck on Java 7 for some time.

Comment: @BoristheSpider isn't a date timezone ignorant? I've also heard it stated that it's always in UTC but I think it's more that there is no timezone tied to it. ??? - thanks - dave

Comment: @DavidThielen that's why we're advising to use the Java 8 Time API (JSR-310) **Backport**, which is a backport of the standard Java 8 classes, intended to be used on previous versions of Java.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand the backport part at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now(                      // Capture the current moment as seen with a wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (a time zone). 
    ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" )  // Use proper time zone names in `continent/region` format. Never use pseudo-zones such as `PST` & `EST`.
).withZoneSameInstant(                  // Adjust from one zone to another. Using immutable objects, so we produce a second distinct `ZonedDateTime` object.
    ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" )     // Same moment, different wall-clock time.
)
```

## java.time & *ThreeTen-Backport*

To gain much of the *java.time* functionality in Java 7, add the *ThreeTen-Backport* library to your project.

Generally best to work with [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) values.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

Apply a time zone only when required by [business logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic) or display to user.

Your `PST` and `EST` values are *not* actual time zones. Use [proper time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
```

Apply to the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Adjust to yet another time zone. The *java.time* framework uses [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So rather than alter (“mutate”) the original, we product a separate distinct object based on the original’s values.

Both `ZonedDateTime` objects and the `Instant` **all represent the very same moment**, the same point on the timeline. This is a crucial concept to understand in date-time handling. Imagine two people, one on the west coast and one on the east coast of North America, talking to each other on the phone. If they both simultaneously look up at the clock hanging on their respective walls, what time do they see? Same moment, different wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId zNewYork = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( zNewYork ) ;  // Same moment, different wall-clock time.
```

All of this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. So search for more examples and discussion.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).